# Modifying Single BigQuery column and writing to new table

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to modify a single column in BigQuery and write the updated data to new table without having to manually keep all of the other columns by hand.  I can accomplish what I would like to do with the following code:

```
row = p | 'ReadFromBigQuery' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query))    
new_row = row | beam.Map(lambda x: (x["col1"], x["col2"], preprocess(x["text_col"]))
output = new_row | beam.Map(lambda (col1, col2, processed_text): {"col1": col1, "col2": col2, "text": processed_text}

output | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(path_to_new_table)
```

However, this requires me to essentially write and keep every column by hand -- if I had 100+ columns (or really even 10+ columns) this would get very messy and cumbersome very fast. Is there a simpler way to run some function (`preprocess()` in this example) over a row and update just that column and still keep the other columns?

Comment: Hint: try representing your data elements not as tuples, but as dictionaries. Then you can use .copy() to copy the dictionary, modify the copy however you wish, and return the modified dictionary.

Comment: Ahh, so this would have to be a separate function that accepts a dictionary and then the modifications can occur there

Comment: @jkff check my answer and let me know if this is what you intended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @jkff, I have figured out how to do this.  the function should take in and receive a dict, and then you can just modify the single element of the dict.  Something like:

```
new_row = row | beam.Map(lambda x: preprocess_text(x, col_to_transform='text_column')`
```

Where preprocess_text() would be something like:

```
def preprocess_text(row, col_to_transform):
  row_copy = row.copy()
  line = row_copy[col_to_transform]
  line = ... # preprocessing transform goes here
  row_copy[col_to_transform] = line

  return row_copy
```

Comment: You need to make a copy of the row instead of modifying the original object. It is not safe to modify the current element passed to a transform.

Comment: @jkff thanks for the suggestion. Is it safe to have the copy be done within the preprocessing function? Or would you advise to have it somewhere else?

Comment: I can't think of a different place to do it. The functions passed to beam.Map, beam.FlatMap, beam.ParDo, beam.Filter etc. are all forbidden from modifying their input elements (or, for that matter, from modifying elements they've already output) - basically, treat elements of PCollections as immutable. So - you have to make the copy in the preprocessing function if that's where you want to modify it.

Comment: @jkff if you think my answer is sufficient would you mind upvoting as a sign of confidence or just let me know if I should add anything else? I don't want to accept my answer if there is more documentation I should include. Thanks!

Comment: @jkff could you point to any more resources explaining why "It is not safe to modify the current element passed to a transform. " and why we would need to make a copy of the row instead of modifying the original object? Looking to get a deeper understanding of what is motivating this.

Comment: In some cases Beam may pass the same object to several transforms in parallel (eg if there's a fork in the pipeline, but there may be other cases). Then one of them may receive an object inadvertently mutated by the other.

Comment: Thanks! I believe that `row.copy()` would be a shallow copy -- is this something to be concerned of at all?

Comment: Or is the risk more on the "other transforms" that are receiving the same input object as opposed to I was thinking the risk was on the one currently undergoing a transformation?

Comment: Yes, you need a deep copy. Beam may actually detect mutations and intentionally fail the pipeline if it detects any.